# Почему плохо использовать абсолютные пути?

Tags: nginx

GOOD:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

BAD:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/yoursite.com/$fastcgi_script_name
```

Источник: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Answer (score 3):

Ответ прост - должно быть только одно место, где все меняется. Если завтра сайт поменяет имя, то придется искать все места, где нужно поменять (а в некоторых местах возможно и не нужно). Если это домашний сайт-поделка на две страницы, то не имеет значения. А если хоть чуточку сложнее - уже может сильно упрощать жизнь.

Comment: А я уже думал что что то с производительностью.